# Is it possible to run a 12v Nema17 Stepper motor remotely with ESP32 over LORA P2P?

Tags: esp32, lora

I'm new to this, but I have 2x ESP32 LoRa modules that I want to setup. I want to be able transmit a signal from one ESP32 LoRa module to the other ESP32 LoRa module over LoRa to run a stepper motor which will be driven by either a L298N or a A4988 Driver on a 12v battery. The idea is no WiFi/Blutooth, latency isn't an issue, and I would like to be able to push a button on the ESP32 to make it run one sketch and another button to run another sketch.

Comment: your questions is synonymous with `Is it possible to send data with ESP32 over LORA P2P?`

Comment: Thank you for the response, basically I want to have 3 buttons on the transmitter end. The receiver module would be waiting for one of the three commands and run the corresponding loop. It seems like it would work but like I said I'm new to this and haven't seen any one doing it P2P. Everything I've seen is LoRaWAN with AT- commands which seems like I'm missing something. ..

Comment: forget about buttons and forget about motors ... first work towards successfuly transmitting a single byte of data

Comment: Thank you again for the response. I have successfully sent messages from one ESP32 LoRa device to another. It doesn't appear that there are any projects online of anyone that I've found that has run a stepper off just LoRa. Transmit data to the other module and execute code to run a stepper through a driver. I'm beginning to think its not possible because there isn't a project I've seen and I've looked extensively at. There are projects that transmit to another module and turn a light on or off, or to module and go through a relay to turn on lamp or appliance.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense ... why would you need to find a ready-made project? ... why would you think that there is no solution? ... if you are able to transmit data, then devise a protocol for controlling a servo ... it can be anything ... for example `S1L45` could mean `turn servo #1 left 45 degrees`